# Get ID of element that called a function

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

How can I get the ID of an element that called a JS function?

*body.jpg* is an image of a dog as the user points his/her mouse around the screen at different parts of the body an enlarged image is shown. The ID of the area element is identical to the image filename minus the folder and extension.

```
<div>
    <img src="images/body.jpg" usemap="#anatomy"/>
</div>

<map name="anatomy">
  <area id="nose" shape="rect" coords="280,240,330,275" onmouseover="zoom()"/>
</map>

<script type="text/javascript">
function zoom()
{
 document.getElementById("preview").src="images/nose.jpg";
}
</script>

<div>
<img id="preview"/>
</div>
```

I've done my research and have come to Stack Overflow as a last resort. I'm prefer a solution that doesn't involve jQuery.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Pass a reference to the element into the function when it is called:

```
<area id="nose" onmouseover="zoom(this);" />

<script>
  function zoom(ele) {
    var id = ele.id;

    console.log('area element id = ' + id);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you know that that'll give you the `<img>` element and not the `<area>` or `<map>` element?  I don't but I'm going to try a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Pointy You're right. I wasn't thinking. I have corrected my example.

Comment: Note: `href="javascript:void(zoom(this));"` returns the Window. More reason to use `onmouseclick` instead.

Answer (score 10):

I'm surprised that nobody has mentioned the use of `this` in the event handler.  It works automatically in modern browsers and can be made to work in other browsers.  If you use `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` to install your event handler, then you can make the value of `this` automatically be assigned to the object the created the event.

Further, the user of programmatically installed event handlers allows you to separate javascript code from HTML which is often considered a good thing.

Here's how you would do that in your code in plain javascript:

Remove the `onmouseover="zoom()"` from your HTML and install the event handler in your javascript like this:

```
// simplified utility function to register an event handler cross-browser
function setEventHandler(obj, name, fn) {
    if (typeof obj == "string") {
        obj = document.getElementById(obj);
    }
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        return(obj.addEventListener(name, fn));
    } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        return(obj.attachEvent("on" + name, function() {return(fn.call(obj));}));
    }
}

function zoom() {
    // you can use "this" here to refer to the object that caused the event
    // this here will refer to the calling object (which in this case is the <map>)
    console.log(this.id);
    document.getElementById("preview").src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344290962_h6JjS-Ti.jpg";
}

// register your event handler
setEventHandler("nose", "mouseover", zoom);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5EQAJ/.

Answer (score 10):

You can use 'this' in event handler:

```
document.getElementById("preview").onmouseover = function() {
    alert(this.id);
}
```

Or pass event object to handler as follows:

```
document.getElementById("preview").onmouseover = function(evt) {
    alert(evt.target.id);
}
```

It's recommended to use attachEvent(for IE < 9)/addEventListener(IE9 and other browsers) to attach events. Example above is for brevity.

```
function myHandler(evt) {
    alert(evt.target.id);
}

var el = document.getElementById("preview");
if (el.addEventListener){
    el.addEventListener('click', myHandler, false); 
} else if (el.attachEvent){
    el.attachEvent('onclick', myHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can code the handler setup like this:

```
<area id="nose" shape="rect" coords="280,240,330,275" onmouseover="zoom.call(this)"/>
```

Then `this` in your handler will refer to the element.  Now, I'll offer the caveat that I'm not 100% sure what happens when you've got a handler in an `<area>` tag, largely because I haven't seen an `<area>` tag in like a decade or so.  I *think* it should give you the image tag, but that could be wrong.

*edit* — yes, it's wrong - you get the `<area>` tag, not the `<img>`.  So you'll have to get that element's parent (the map), and then find the image that's using it (that is, the `<img>` whose "usemap" attribute refers to the map's name).

*edit again* — except it doesn't matter because you **want** the area's "id" durr.  Sorry for not reading correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I know you don't want a jQuery solution but including javascript inside HTML is a big no no.

I mean you can do it but there are lots of reasons why you shouldn't (read up on unobtrusive javascript if you want the details).

So in the interest of other people who may see this question, here is the jQuery solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('area').mouseover(function(event) {
    $('#preview').attr('src', 'images/' + $(event.srcElement).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

The major benefit is you don't mix javascript code with HTML. Further more, you only need to write this once and it will work for all  tags as opposed to having to specify the handler for each  separately.

Additional benefit is that every jQuery handler receives an event object that contains a lot of useful data - such as the source of the event, type of the event and so on making it much easier to write the kind of code you are after.

Finally since it's jQuery you don't need to think about cross-browser stuff - a major benefit especially when dealing with events.

Answer (score 0):

i also want this to happen , 
so just pass the id of the element in the called function and used in my js file :

```
function copy(i,n)
{
 var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(document.getElementById(i));
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
window.getSelection().addRange(range); 
document.execCommand('copy');
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
document.getElementById(n).value = "Copied";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For others unexpectedly getting the Window element, a common pitfall:

```
<a href="javascript:myfunction(this)">click here</a>
```

which actually scopes `this` to the Window object. Instead:

```
<a href="javascript:nop()" onclick="myfunction(this)">click here</a>
```

passes the `a` object as expected. (nop() is just any empty function.)

Answer (score 0):

If you setup a listener like this:

```
buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-group")
for(let i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => { btnClicked(e);},false);
}
```

then you can get the id like this:

```
function btnClicked(e){
  console.log(e.target.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## First Way: Send trigger element using `this`

```
<button id="btn01" onClick="myFun(this)">B1</button>
<button id="btn02" onClick="myFun(this)">B2</button>
<button id="btn03" onClick="myFun(this)">B3</button>

<script>
  function myFun(trigger_element)
  {
      // Get your element:
      var clicked_element = trigger_element

      alert(clicked_element.id + "Was clicked!!!");
  }
</script>
```

> This way send an object of type: `HTMLElement` and you get the element itself. you don't need to care if the element has an id or any other property. And it works by itself just fine.

---

## Second Way: Send trigger element id using `this.id`

```
<button id="btn01" onClick="myFun(this.id)">B1</button>
<button id="btn02" onClick="myFun(this.id)">B2</button>
<button id="btn03" onClick="myFun(this.id)">B3</button>

<script>
  function myFun(clicked_id)
  {
      // Get your element:
      var clicked_element = document.getElementById(clicked_id)

      alert(clicked_id + "Was clicked!!!");
  }
</script>
```

> This way send an object of type: `String` and you DO NOT get the element itself. So before use, you need to make sure that your element already has an id.
>
> You mustn't send the element id by yourself such as `onClick="myFun(btn02)"`. it's not CLEAN CODE and it makes your code lose functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, you have a button like this:

```
<button id="btn1" onclick="doSomething()">Do something</button>
```

In the function, you can reach the id with this way:

```
function doSomething() {
    let callerElementId = event.srcElement.id;
    console.log(callerElementId);
}
```