# Is there a simple way to make a function get the ID of the tag that called it?

Tags: javascript, function

I have this code like: `<div id = "trg" onclick = "swap()">`. so my swap function needs to get the ID of the tag that called it. In this case `"trg"`. My function is like:

```
function swap(){
    document.getElementById( this??? ).id = "trgClicked"; //I want to change its ID
    document.getElementById( this??? ).className = "trgClicked"; //and class
}
```

I know I could just use the elements specific ID but I have alot of these buttons and it would be simpler if I could just get the ID of the element calling it. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this (Using `inline` event `this` won't work as expected as mentioned in another answer)

```js
function swap(element)
{
    alert(element.id); // trg
}
```

```html
<div id="trg" onclick="swap(this)">Click Me</div>
```

Comment: i changed "switch" to "swap" in my original post, can u edit answer? Sorry for using switch to begin with..very stupid i know

Comment: Using inline event this will work as expected if using swap.call(this), instead of swap().  http://jsfiddle.net/we8aqzge/1/

Comment: I had to put element.id in a variable first, works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

HTML

```
<div id = "trg" onclick = "swap.call(this)">
```

javascript

```
function swap(){
    this.id = "trgClicked"; //I want to change its ID
    this.className = "trgClicked"; //and class
}
```

Comment: In this case (`inline event`) `this` is the default global (`window`) object.

Comment: Changing context of swap method with .call

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass it in the function as a parameter

try this actually
[Get ID of element that called a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627161/get-id-of-element-that-called-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are asking how to easily change the id or class of an element using a function.
This is what works perfectly for the id.

```
function switched(element, attrToChange, newAttribute){
    var selection = document.getElementById(element);
    var attr = selection.setAttribute(attrToChange, newAttribute);
}

switched('scores', 'id', 'scored');
```

This other one is for class change

```
function switched(element, attrToChange, newAttribute){
    var selection = document.getElementsByClassName(element)[0];
    var attr = selection.setAttribute(attrToChange, newAttribute);
}

switched('scores', 'id', 'scored');
```