# Finding Client Id of User Control in External JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls, infragistics

In my asp.net application, several user control's(.ascx) are rendered under a parent page(.aspx). In each user control, i call javascript functions and some other Infragistics client side events(Which can only accept certain param's). These functions are written in an external javascript file and is included from the parent page.

The problem is when i use $find("<%= Me.grdDataTable.ClientID%>") inside each function to find the user control from where the call came from, it returns as null. I cannot change the arguments passed into some of the JS methods as they are related to Infragistics events which accept only specific arguments.

Is there a way to find the Client Id of the user control from where the JavaScript method is called without introducing an input argument to the JS methods?

Some of the JS methods i use:

```
function WebDataGridControl_AddRow() {    
    // Commit the row that was added to ROWADDING server event
    $find("<%= Me.grdDataTable.ClientID%>")
     .get_behaviors()
     .get_editingCore()
     .get_behaviors().get_rowAdding()._commitRow();
}
function WebDataGridControl_RowSelection_Changed(webDataGrid, evntArgs) {
    // When row is changed, get the index of the row selected
    var grid = $find("<%= Me.grdDataTable.ClientID%>");
    var gridBehaviors = grid.get_behaviors();
    var row = gridBehaviors.get_selection().get_selectedRows().getItem(0);
    $('#<%=hdnEditRow.ClientID%>').val(row.get_index());
}
```

Thanks,
AV

Comment: I'm not familiar with WebForms, but given that you can't add parameters to your javascript function you could use the DOM as some sort of "global variable". When rendering your page, create a hidden input with the client id on it, something like: `<input id="gridTableId" type="hidden" value="<%= MyServerVariable%>" />`, then from your JS code, read the value from the input: `var gridId = $("gridTableId").val();`

Comment: Since there are multiple user controls rendered in the same parent page and if each user control sets the client id to the hidden variable gridTableId, then it will be an issue since "$("gridTableId").val()" sees multiple hidden variables with the same # id and may pick the first one.

Comment: Oh, so you can have different client ids rendered in the same page. Remember that JavaScript is not strict, so you could create a new parameter in the function without breaking the Infragistics, by the way, how did this function works in Infragistics?? One thing you could do is to rely on the `this` inside your function, it should be populated with the source DOM elements with your function is triggered through an event, check this link for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7627711/967736